# Calling a React Hook from a Button Click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can't get my head around how hooks are called from a function.  I have a button [left most column of the image].  You click and it would save the data row to the SessionStore.  Throws an error about "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."  Any idea how to solve this ?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkZ1b.png)

```
   import { useSessionStorage } from "../components/SessionStore";
    
    function useStore(tableName, row) {
        // tried calling this in this onclick but the same error
        useSessionStorage(tableName, row);
    }
    
    // abbreviated to show just the column with the button click - feeds 
    // into {columns} of BootstrapTable - "react-bootstrap-table-next";
    const endPoint = [
        {
            dataField: 'df1',
            isDummyField: true,
            text: 'Local Store',
            formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
    
                return (
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-light"
                        onClick={() => {
                            useStore("editTable", row);
                        }}
    
                    >{row.id}</button>
                );
            },
            editable: false
        }
    ];
```

Comment: follow what the error says; https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

In React, certain names have an implicit meaning.
For instance, whenever you name a function in [Pascal-case](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/Pascal-case), i.e. - with a capitalized first letter, React automatically assumes that you are creating a component.
Another example is with any function name that starts with "use", as React assumes you are creating a hook.

Now that we've established **how** React knows you are creating a hook, let's take the error into account.
The error states that React hooks can only be called in the main function body.
So calling it directly in an `onClick` attribute won't work.

We should also consider how the standard API structure of React hooks.
Usually a hook would return a value / function that we would then be able to assign to a variable and use within another hook or a component (also a React rule).

So let's take your example:

```
// We have the `useStore` hook:
function useStore(tableName, row) {
   // Now we are returning a function.
   return useSessionStorage(tableName, row);
}

// Then we have our React component where we would like to use the hook:
function Foo() {
   const store = useStore(tableName, row);

   // ...rest of code

   return (
      // Here we have the onClick with the function from the hook which we could now use:
      <button onClick={store}>Click me!</button>
   )
}
```